# Uso do -webkit-* e -moz-*

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Os prefixos `-webkit-` ou `-moz-` devem ser usados para elementos que funcionam sem o uso desses (como `box-shadow`)?

Normalmente quem utiliza Chrome e Firefox tem as versões que suportam muitos elementos, o que torna desnecessário acrescentar estes códigos.

Answer (score 0):

O uso dos elementos de browser como o webkit e o moz é para ser usados apenas quando a aplicação de estilo não é renderizada em browsers que não suportam o CSS3. Os elementos que funcionam sem a declaração deles é feita normalmente.